# how to set the ajax results to block template using cs cart?

Tags: php, ajax, smarty, cs-cart

I'm new to cs cart. I need to  pass the ajax results to blocks template file.

I have the following code in my controller :-

```
if($mode=='drill')
{
     $id=166;
     Registry::get('view')->assign('pid', $id);
     $all_subcategory=fn_get_subcategories($id);
             foreach($all_subcategory as $value){
               $sub_cat[$value['category_id']]=$value['category'];
             }
             Registry::get('view')->assign('all_year', $sub_cat);
             Registry::get('view')->display('templates/blocks/product_filters/components/drillsearch.tpl');
             Registry::get('view')->assign('all_year', $sub_cat);
return $sub_cat;

  }


I have the following code in drillsearch.tpl :-


 function fun(){
    var sBase = location.href.substr(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

   $.ajax({
    url: sBase+"index.php?dispatch=drill.drill",
        data: 123 ,
        type: "POST",
         success: function(data) {
          alert("sfd");
         alert(data);
    },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert('failed');
     alert(xhr.responseText);
   }
});   
}
```

Here the ajax results does not  assign templates/blocks/product_filters/components/drillsearch.tpl .How to solve it .Please help me

Answer (score 1):

When sending a request from a view to a controller, you can "reply" to the view by simply using this:

```
            Registry::get('ajax')->assign('all_year', $sub_cat);
```

I believe this shall work just fine, as the variable you need will be available to your AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

## PHP

```
if($mode=='drill'){
     $id=166;
     $all_subcategory=fn_get_subcategories($id);
     foreach($all_subcategory as $value){
        $sub_cat[$value['category_id']]=$value['category'];
     }

     header('Content-Type: application/json');             
     echo json_encode($sub_cat);
     exit;
}
```

## TPL

```
function fun(){
     $.ajax({
        url: Tygh.index_script+"?dispatch=drill.drill",
            data: { variable: '123' },
            type: "GET",
            success: function(categories) {
                for(var category_id in categories){
                    console.log(category_id+' > '+categories[category_id]);
                }
            }
     });
}
```

## Results

[image: http://prntscr.com/69zagm]

I hope that helps,